# Slice pandas series based on type of elements

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following pandas series:

```
s = pd.Series([1,'1',1.0])
```

```
s.dtype
dtype('O')
```

When I check the types of each element I get the following:

```
type(s.iloc[0])
<class 'int'>

type(s.iloc[1])
<class 'str'>

type(s.iloc[2])
<class 'float'>
```

Is there a way to slice the pandas series based on the type of the elements?

Something like the following:

```
mask = s.types == 'str' # this doesn't exist

s[mask]
1    1
dtype: object
```

Ideally, I would want something that doesn't use loops (such as apply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda function through `Series.apply` in combination with `isintance`:

```
s.loc[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention it in the question but I was searching for something vectorized, because if I have a lot of rows that would be slow

Comment: I don't think there's any out-of-the-box pandas method for this. Most will still apply a for loop in the background. You could always use numpy's [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) in order to make it more readable (`vec_isinstance = np.vectorize(isinstance); s.loc[vec_isinstance(s, str)]`, but even that is implemented as a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Series.map` + `type:`

```
s[s.map(type).eq(str)]
```

I think this should be faster since the function is simpler

Comment: Does map use loops?

Comment: Yes, 
but it really is necessary here because there is no pandas method to do this

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191832/checking-if-a-data-series-is-strings

Comment: this would use loops only to map getting the type of each yield in the series. And then check using `boolean indexing` with `Series.eq`, I think this is better because it avoids checking inside the loop