# Vectorized Custom function not working as expected In pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, vectorization

With [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN5d490_KKk) pycon talk as a source.

```
def clean_string(item):
    if type(item)==type(1):
        return item
    else:
        return np.nan
```

dataframe object has a column containing numerical and string data, I want to change strings to `np.nan`
while leaving numerical data as it is.

This approach is working fine

```
df['Energy Supply'].apply(clean_string)
```

but when I am trying to use vectorisation,  values of all the column items changed to `np.nan`

```
df['Energy Supply'] = clean_string(df['Energy Supply'])  # vectorisation
```

but the above method is converting all items to `np.nan`. I believe this is because `type(item)` in `clean_string` function is `pd.Series` type.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

PS: I am a beginner in `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorizing an operation in pandas isn't always possible. I'm not aware of a pandas built-in vectorized way to get the type of the elements in a Series, so your `.apply()` solution may be the best approach.

The reason that your code doesn't work in the second case is that you are passing the entire Series to your `clean_string()` function. It compares the type of the Series to `type(1)`, which is `False` and then returns one value `np.nan`. Pandas automatically broadcasts this value when assigning it back to the df, so you get a column of `NaN`. In order to avoid this, you would have to loop over all of the elements in the Series in your `clean_string()` function.

Out of curiosity, I tried a few other approaches to see if any of them would be faster than your version. To test, I created 10,000 and 100,000 element `pd.Series` with alternating integer and string values:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(i if i%2==0 else str(i) for i in range(10000))
s2 = pd.Series(i if i%2==0 else str(i) for i in range(100000))
```

These tests are done using pandas 1.0.3 and python 3.8.

### Baseline using `clean_string()`

```py
In []: %timeit s.apply(clean_string)
3.75 ms ± 14.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In []: %timeit s2.apply(clean_string)
39.5 ms ± 301 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

### `Series.str` methods

An alternative way to test for strings vs. non-strings would be to use the built-in `.str` functions on the Series, for example, if you apply `.str.len()`, it will return `NaN` for any non-strings in the Series. These are even called "[Vectorized String Methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods)" in pandas documentation, so maybe they will be more efficient.

```py
In []: %timeit s.mask(s.str.len()>0)
6 ms ± 39.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In []: %timeit s2.mask(s2.str.len()>0)
56.8 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Unfortunately, this approach is slower than the `.apply()`. Despite being "vectorized" it doesn't look like this is a better approach. It is also not quite identical to the logic of `clean_string()` because it is testing for elements that are strings not for elements that are integers.

### Applying `type` directly to the Series

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43191959/7517724), I decided to test using `.apply()` with `type` to get the type of each element. Once we know the type, compare to `int` and use the `.mask()` method to convert any non-integers to `NaN`.

```py
In []: %timeit s.mask(s.apply(type)!=int)
1.88 ms ± 4.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In []: %timeit s2.mask(s2.apply(type)!=int)
15.2 ms ± 32.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This turns out to be the fastest approach that I've found.